# Android: AlertDialog looks different in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I have an app which uses TabLayout and Fragments, however my initial log in screen is a standard Activity.  When I show an alert dialog from the Login screen, the look of the dialog is completely different from when I show one from inside of a fragment.

**From Login Screen**

[image]

**From inside of Fragment**

[image]

The code that I use to show the alertDialog is the following class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

class AlertDialogManager {

    private AlertDialog alertDialog;
    private Context mContext;

    public void showAlertDialog(final Activity activity, String title, String message, Boolean status, final Boolean finishOnClose) {
        // Set our context correctly based on what was passed in activity
        mContext = (activity.getParent()!=null) ? mContext = activity.getParent() : activity;

        // Create our alertDialog Builder
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);        

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        // Setting alert dialog icon
        if(status != null) alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.icon_check : R.drawable.icon_alert);

        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // if the user passed in TRUE for the finishOnClose param - we call try onBackPressed first and if that fails, call finish()
                if (finishOnClose) {
                    try {
                        activity.onBackPressed();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        activity.finish();
                    }               
                }
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

To show one in an Activity I use the following:

```
// At the top of my activity I declare
private final AlertDialogManager alertDialog = new AlertDialogManager();

// Then where I want to show one I use this
alertDialog.showAlertDialog(MyActivity.this, "Title", "Message", false, false);
```

To show one in a Fragment I use the following:

```
// At the top of my fragment I declare
private final AlertDialogManager alertDialog = new AlertDialogManager();

alertDialog.showAlertDialog(getActivity(), "Title", "Message", false, false);
```

Can anyone explain why I would get the 2 completely different "themes" on my dialog when calling from an Activity vs Fragment?  I'm stumped.

thank you!!!

Comment: two different versions of Android ?

Comment: @Blackbelt - how can I check for that?  I have the compileSdkVersion as 23, minSdkVersion as 19 and targetSdkVersion as 23 - my build.gradle

Comment: I mean on the device where you are running the app. Which version of AlertDialog are you using ? `v7.app.AlertDialog` ? Check your imports

Comment: I do not have an import on the fragments or activities, I only have an import inside of the AlertDialogManager class as seen in my code above.  import android.app.AlertDialog;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the older API version you are supporting? because you can use the AlertDialog builde since the API 11. If you are supporting older versions, you have to set the theme.

Example:

```
    ContextThemeWrapper theme;
    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
        theme = new ContextThemeWrapper( context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar );
    }
    else {
        theme= new ContextThemeWrapper( context, android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar );
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(theme);
```

Hope this help.

Comment: my minSdkVersion is 19, my targetSdkVersion is 23 and my compileSdkVersion is 23

Comment: Maybe there is a problem calling different styles, I can not imagine another solution right now, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to add the following to the  declaration in my manifest for my Login activity

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```